# Wi-Fi emulator possible for a Windows10 desktop computer?

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter

Conditions: Windows 10, with cable connection to ethernet, no Wi-Fi hardware, not to buy USB Wi-Fi adapter.

The Problem: I have an Android phone, in addition to the desktop computer running Windows 10. Both have the same app installed (Android & Windows 10 version respectively). For the two apps to connect, they require the phone & desktop both be connected to Wi-Fi with the same SSID. I want to fulfill this requirement by emulating a WiFi on my desktop.

Goal: **Emulate WiFi**. Make it look like my computer is connected to the emulated WiFi, and under the hood access internet via my cable connection.

Would this be possible and how?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have an Android phone and a desktop. Each has the same APP (android & desktop version respectively). For the two APPs to connect, they require the phone & desktop both connected to WIFI of the same SSID. I want to fulfill this requirement by emulating a WiFi on my desktop.

Comment: @RaymondKwok: These are critical details, which need to be part of the question. I took the liberty of editing it in, feel free to re-edit.

Comment: Thank you @sleske

Comment: Usually "Same SSID" is completely unrelated to whether such apps can connect to each other, and so is Wi-Fi in general (Android apps don't have nearly enough permissions for that to make a difference) – the real requirement tends to be "same broadcast domain", with SSIDs being used as a kind of analogy / proxy term only. Do you have any documentation for your specific apps that says they require Wi-Fi?

Comment: seems there is no easy way for my goal.